# firebird insert into returning into another insert

Tags: firebird

I'm using Firebird as DB and I need to do this:

```
INSERT INTO TG (ID, UID, GID) 
    SELECT (INSERT INTO TBO VALUES (GEN_ID('o',1)) RETURNING ID), UID, 10 
    FROM TBL l 
    WHERE l.is=1
```

the part with select is OK when I use:

```
SELECT (GEN_ID('o',1)), UID, 10 
    FROM TBL l 
    WHERE l.is=1
```

but I need the `ID` in other table for dependency first.

I know about something called procedures but I have no idea how to use them. Is there an option to do this using SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [EXECUTE BLOCK](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-execblock.html) statement. It allow you to execute multiple statements in one "batch" or write complex logic if you cannot embed it in one SQL query.

Inside EXECUTE BLOCK you can write mutiple commands using [PSQL](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-psql.html).

EB allow input params, output params (yes you can use it as a table), local variables, if statement, while, for select etc... very powerfull tool.

Just prepare your block and execute it like simple SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler aproach would be to use triggers.
In this example it would be a before insert trigger.
Something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TG_BI0 FOR TABLE TG ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT 0
AS
BEGIN
    /* Before insert create a new record in TBO */
    INSERT INTO TBO (ID) VALUES (NEW.ID);
END
```

After having this trigger you shloud only insert records in TG.

```
INSERT INTO TG (ID, UID, GID)
VALUES (GEN_ID('o',1), 'SOME_UUID', 10)
```